# Worldbuilding Software (Procedural Generation?)

Tags: windows

I'm looking for (procedural generation?) software than can help me *build* a *world* that I will use in my D&D games. I've been fighting with Fractal Terrains and Wilbur, as well as my own "manual" methods of mapmaking in Photoshop.

It would ideally meet the following criteria:

- Work on a global scale (eg for the sake of projecting onto google earth or otherwise). Only being able to create flat sections of world that don't form part of a planet is not useful to me.
- Work on a local scale as part of the global scale (just say that the world scale map is an approximation that loses detail as you zoom in - I would like to be able to zoom in on a certain part of the world and use/edit the terrain there).
- Can "paint in" terrain features and adjust them to make them more realistic (eg, just say that a mountain is required where plate tectonics wouldn't normally allow for one - I would want to be able to paint in a mountain or higher elevation, and then be able to apply erosion-style filters to blend it in with the area around the mountain)
- Can correctly place natural features - such as mountains, rivers and lakes in realistic positions.
- Can correctly determine and place biomes and climate zones etc. Ideally (not sure how achievable this is), if I were to place the afformentioned "unnatural" mountain range in a place that would create a rainshadow desert, I would want it to either change the climate/biome to suit or tell me how it "should" be.
- Can provide satellite-style images of the terrain (doesn't need to be perfectly photorealistic, but preferably more than symbolic blobs or hexes.
- Ideally, the software would be as accessible to lay people as possible. The fact that I'm asking this question should tell you that I'm not a graphics industry insider, and the most complex coding I am capable of is simple formulas in Excel.

Things it **doesn't** need to do (but optionally can) are:

- Any sort of tricky or intensive 3D modelling. This will almost entirely be used for building the world and then making maps out of it - the maps I will probably continue do in photoshop, using the generated world primarily for reference. This will never be used for commercial purposes, and will never be transferred a video game or movie.

I've been looking at things like Terragen, World Machine, World Creator and the like, and they seem great. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out through their websites if they fulfill the criteria I've laid out, because their applications seem much more grandiose in scale. I'm clearly not their target demographic (unpaid hobbyist with no background in graphic design). They all want to show off how amazingly realistic their terrain can look, and how well it synergises with other software, how it can or has been used in movies and games. I have no idea if: A) the criteria I've outlined is so obviously fulfilled that it is a baseline that they don't bother mentioning, or B) what I'm after is something that doesn't exist, or I should find somewhere else.

Thanks in advance for any and all help given.

Comment: Clarification, do you want to create an entire globe? Or do you want to be able to extend the map indefinitely on a flat plane? Bear in mind that the latter is significantly easier than the former.

Comment: @DubberRucky Create a globe. In fractal terrains, you will work on the map as a flat projection, and then it can be overlaid onto a google earth template to allow you to zoom and pan around the planet.